# Как получить значение параметра по имени в цикле

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Есть скрипт который получает данные из запроса. Я отправляю `count` -  означает количество параметров которые необходимо достать, и сами параметры в следующей форме: `product1` `productQuant1`, `product2` `productQuant2`, то есть в данном случает `count=2`. Задача в том, чтобы в цикле извлечь все параметры, обращаясь к ним по названию, составленным из `product` + `i`, где `i` это переменная цикла.
Я пробовал конкатенацию, не работает.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    var product = request.parameter.product + i;
    var productQuant = request.parameter.productQuant + i;
    sheet.appendRow([product, productQuant]);
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример запроса.

Comment: "https:/ /script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxFZC9YPpG1-A_StZ583S0jtkmApNOEFclM8eKJ3bLB0zwiHN0/exec?product1=Americano&product2=Pizza&productQuant1=2&productQuant2=1&count=2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, вам нужно обратиться к свойсву объекта по его ключу. Например, для `product` необходимо вызвать `e.parameter['product' + (i + 1)]`

```
function doGet(e) {
  var count = e.parameter.count || 0;
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    values.push([e.parameter['product' + (i + 1)], e.parameter[
      'productQuant' + (i + 1)]]);
  /*
    The sheet has to exist.
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC').getSheets()[0];         
  */
  if(values.length)
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
      .setValues(values);
}
```